# Loop in string and get word between 2 character and save to list

Tags: asp.net, string, filter

we have string example : 
**www.example.com/default.aspx?code-1/price-2/code-4/**
i want to get integers from code and price and save to list of integers.
for example , 1 and 4 are codes , 2 is price for filter in site.

*InBetween = GetStringInBetween("Brand-", "/", Example, false, false);*

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simple program that completes your requirement.

```
    class Program
{
    public void GetCodesAndPrice(string url,out List<int> listOfCodes, out List<int> listOfPrice )
    {
        listOfCodes=new List<int>();
        listOfPrice = new List<int>();
        url = url.Substring(url.IndexOf('?')+1);
        var strArray = url.Split('/');
        foreach (string s in strArray)
        {
            if(s.ToLower().Contains("code"))
                listOfCodes.Add(GetIntValue(s));

            else if(s.ToLower().Contains("price"))
                listOfPrice.Add(GetIntValue(s));
        }

        // Now you have list of price in "listOfPrice" and codes in "listOfCodes",
        // If you want to return these two list then declare as out

    }
    public int GetIntValue(string str)
    {
        try
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(str.IndexOf('-') + 1));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            // Handle your exception over here
        }
        return 0; // It depends on you what do you want to return if exception occurs in this function
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        var prog = new Program();
        List<int> listOfCodes;
        List<int> listOfPrice;
            prog.GetCodesAndPrice("www.example.com/default.aspx?code-1/price-2/code-4/", out listOfCodes,out listOfPrice);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It is complete console program. Test it and Embed in your program. Hope this will help you